# In HoTT, what is the hlevel of $S^1$?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I think there's an obvious fact that `(base = base) = Z` hence `isSet (base = base)` is inhabited. However, is it also true that `∀x. ∀y. (x = y) = Z` in HoTT? Or does `∀x. ∀y. isSe (x = y)` hold in HoTT?

Comment: It is definitely not true that `∀x. ∀y. (x = y) = Z`. You cannot continuously choose the isomorphism.

Comment: @Trebor edited to reflect that

Comment: Did you look at the HoTT book for an answer? I would be quite surprised if it isn't in there.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I tried, but I didn't see it in the subsection that talks about circles.

Comment: We may even easily disprove that “Π x y, (x = y) = ℤ”. It implies “Π y, (base = y) = ℤ”, but we know that “Π y, (base = y) = helix(y)”; so “Π y, helix(y) = ℤ”, while helix isn’t constant, because helix(loop) ≠ idp(ℤ). https://github.com/forked-from-1kasper/ground_zero/blob/505319dcbcbfa8318bb08008b418520afeaae4a7/GroundZero/HITs/Circle.lean#L621-L638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a cubical solution, then [here](https://agda.github.io/cubical/Cubical.HITs.S1.Properties.html#844) it is. It is straightforward to obtain a similar HoTT solution.

As a reminder, the h-level hierarchy goes `isContr -> isProp -> isSet -> isGroupoid -> is2Groupoid -> ...`. I never remembered the actual numbering of the levels, so there.